# vba run other excel files macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have following code:

```
Sub MacroRunner()
Dim Nomefile As String, Nomefolder As String
Nomefolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Nomefile = Dir(Nomefolder & "\*.xlsb")
Workbooks.Open (Nomefolder & "\" & Nomefile)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Select
Application.Run "Nomefile!listaIdprodotto"  '<-------- "nomefile" variable not returned

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

The issue is in line marked by a left arrow; Excel doesn't return variable value making itself unable to find asked Macro to be executed.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your code encounter any error messages?  If `nomefile` is blank I would expect the line `Workbooks.Open (Nomefolder & "\" & Nomefile)` to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer a bit differently (in case that `Nomefile.xlsb` is the file):

```
Application.Run "'Nomefile.xlsb'!listaIdprodotto"
```

Or even (in case that `Nomefile` is a variable):

```
Application.Run "'" & Nomefile & "'!listaIdprodotto"
```

[Source](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to be more specific about what files and sheets you want to act on.

`Nomefolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path`
This isn't necessarily the workbook containing the code.  If you create a new workbook immediately before running the code then this will equal an empty string - it's whichever workbook is currently on top (active).

`Nomefile = Dir(Nomefolder & "\*.xlsb")`
This will return the first file in the folder that has an `xlsb` extension.  If todays file wasn't created it will return the previous file and run yesterdays update again.
If it's a file that's generated each day then look for the file name with the correct date.

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Select`
Again - same problem with `ActiveWorkbook`.  This is also looking at the second sheet in the tab order which may not be the sheet you're after if someone moved it.  Reference the sheet by name (which could still be changed).  It would be better to reference by sheet CodeName which can't be changed by the user, but that opens a different kettle of worms as the sheet you're referencing isn't in the workbook containing the code.

`Application.Run "Nomefile!listaIdprodotto"`
As you've enclosed `Nomefile` within the double quotes it's not seeing it as a variable but as a file called *Nomefile*.  To see it as a variable it needs to be written as `Application.Run Nomefile & "!listaIdprodotto"`.  If the file name contains spaces then it needs to be written as Vityata has written:  `Application.Run "'" & Nomefile & "'!listaIdprodotto"`.  This encloses the file name in single quotes.

I'd rewrite the code as:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim Nomefile As String, Nomefolder As String
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    'Nomefolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Nomefolder = ThisWorkbook.Path
    'Nomefile = Dir(Nomefolder & "\*.xlsb")
    Nomefile = Nomefolder & "\WorkbookWithCode.xlsb"

    'Open the workbook, run the code and close the workbook.
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(Nomefile)
    Application.Run "'" & wrkBk.Name & "'!listaIdprodotto"
    wrkBk.Close

End Sub
```

The main difference here is that I set the whole workbook to a variable - `Set wrkBk = ....`.  From there on I can always reference the correct workbook and don't have to worry whether it's *Active* or not.

Comment: all your tips works fine. i knew it was a matter of syntax. thanks to all for assisting me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!